# Explanation of htaccess conditions

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to know, what the following .htaccess code does:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   (.*)=http(.*)   [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   (.*)=ftp(.*)   [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   (.*)urlx=(.*)   [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)  - [F]
```

Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule checks whether any of those prohibited patterns are present in the QUERY_STRING and if they it is sending forbidden error to client browser.

Patterns are:

1. =http
2. =ftp
3. urlx=